# writing and reading into image's header

Tags: c++, image, file-io, binary

I have an image namely **warren.jpg**. I wrote the following code to write my name into its header rendering image viewer programs unable to open the file. Then I wrote the next code to read everything apart from my name and write it into another file. Following are the two programs:-

```
Code 1:

int main () {

  std::ofstream is ("warren.jpg", ios::binary|ios::out);

  if (is) {
    // get length of file:
    is.seekp(0,is.beg);
    char *wr= "avinash";
    is.write(wr, 7);
    is.close();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

```
Code 2:
int main () {

    std::ifstream is ("warren.jpg", ios::binary|ios::in);

  if (is) {
    // get length of file:
    is.seekg (0, is.end);
    int length = is.tellg();
    is.seekg (0, is.beg);

    char *name= new char[7];
    char * buffer = new char[length-7]();
    is.read (name,7);
    is.read (buffer,length-7);
    cout<<name[0]<<name[1]<<name[6]<<endl; //'avh' is printed

    std::ofstream os;
    os.open("warrennew.jpg", ios::binary|ios::out);
    if(os)
    {
        os.write(buffer, length-7);
        cout<<"ok"<<endl;   /this was printed in the output
    }
    delete name;
    delete buffer;
  return 0;
}
}
```

My problem is that the file which is getting created(**warrennew.jpg**), is of 0 bytes. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Your output file isn't being closed, try closing it after the if(os) block.

Comment: @Bunnit..I did..it had no effect....although that was a valid point,thanks

Comment: @Bunnit..I found the error...actually when I wrote avinash into the image, the whole image was reduced to 7 bytes...any idea which mode should I open the file in to avoid this from happening?

Comment: Yes should have noticed that, if the space for your name already exists in the file then you can use std::fstream to overwrite part of a file, almost identically to how you have it now.  Otherwise I think the only way is to copy the header into a new file and then copy the rest of the old file(the image part).  Then rename this file to be the same as the old one/delete the old one.

Comment: @Bunnit...agreed..but I can't understand why the file size gets reduced...the 'avinash' should just have overwritten the data in the first 7 bytes leaving the other bytes following it untouched i.e. the file size shouldn't have changed